# Setting onclickListener for google map without overriding the previous one

Tags: android, google-maps

```
private LocationManager manager;
private TextView tv;
private MapController control;
private GeoPoint chosen = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.placechooser);
    final MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.gmap);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    chosen = map.getProjection().fromPixels(
                                                  (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                    tv.setText((chosen.getLatitudeE6() / (Math.pow(10,6)) + "," + (chosen.getLongitudeE6() / (Math.pow(10,6)))));
                    return true;
            }
    });
```

this code snippet works and all, i can see the google map and when i press on certain points on the map i do get expected results on my TextView but the map is not moving and not responding as it should, i guess the built in onclicklistener was overrided by mine how can i fix this?

Things i tried:

1. i tried looking for a getOnClickLisetener to preserve it and activate it on my click listener but there is no such method
2. i tried creating MapOverlay class and copied the on touch functionallity to its onTouch method, not only that the map didnt move, i was also recieving null result from map.getProjection().

how can i overcome this?

Comment: have you tried returning false instead of true in your onTouchListener?

Comment: yep, actually i tried turning it to true because it didnt work with the false...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
control = map.getController();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your CustomMapview which extends Mapview.

In it, override onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) method.

like this:

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        //your logic

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

in your logic, you can fire your custom listener, which will inform your activity which coordinate has been pressed so you can update your textview accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit complicated but you should be able to do it by subclassing `MapView`.

Within your `MapView` class create an internal member class (lets call it `CompositeListener`) similar to the answer in this question: [android- multi onClick listener in one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587299/android-multi-onclick-listener-in-one-button) and create an instance of that class.

During `onCreate` pass `MapView.mOnClickListener` to your `CompositeListener` instance.

Also override the `setOnClickListener` method and pass any listeners set on your custom `MapView` class to your `CompositeListener` instance.

Finally set your `CompositeListener` instance to be the `onClickListener` for your `MapView` using the `super.setOnClickListener` method.

Keep in mind that I have not tested this, so it might require some additional coding to get it working properly.